# Set Icon with Text in a Tabbed Activity

Tags: android, android-tablayout, android-tabbed-activity

I'm trying to implement a icons with text in my `tabbed-activity`. I don't understand how to visualize the icons.

this is the code:

`tab_layout.xml`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="fixed">
```

`tab.java`:

```
private int[] imageResId = {
            R.drawable.ic_one,
            R.drawable.icona_storia,
            R.drawable.icona_piatti_tipici,
            R.drawable.icona_monumenti
    };

    private Context context;
    private String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "Meteo", "Locali", "InfoCittà", "Mappa" };

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
        Drawable image = context.getResources().getDrawable(imageResId[position]);
        image.setBounds(0, 0, image.getIntrinsicWidth(), image.getIntrinsicHeight());
        SpannableString sb = new SpannableString("   " + tabTitles[position]);
        ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(image, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
        sb.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        return sb;
    }
```

This is the final result:
[image]

Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this,

```
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_home));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_profile));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_settings));
```

[See more details here](https://gist.github.com/faizsiddiqui/9af9cea9051335e1ad3f)

Comment: Thank you, but this can't resolve my problem, I want icons with alongside text, this option give me or just icons or just text

Comment: I tried tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_settings).setText("hello")); and now it looks good

Comment: Ok thank you, now it worked perfectly, so +1 deserved

Comment: but if I want the icon to the left of the text, how  should I do it?

Comment: Now I have the icon and below the text, I would like to have both in the same line